# How to make groups of divs the same width using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, user-experience

I've got a group of buttons (divs) which I would like to be the same length for all buttons within a logical group.

I could simply do a `min-length` for the CSS style of the button, however some button groups are short, while others are very long. This makes a uniform `min-length` either insufficient for long groups or wasteful/stupid looking for short ones. Additionally, multiple groups (short and long) can appear on the same screen.

[image: Example of Button Layouts]

(These divs are all styled with `display: inline-block`, so that's why they don't fill the width of the container)

I've thought of a few nasty solutions to this, but none are preferable:

- Set a specific `min-length` for each group
- Use JavaScript to resize the buttons

I was wondering if there was a generic, pure CSS solution to the above problem instead of using either of these methods. Thanks for any help you can provide.

---

**Edit**: Here is the markup and CSS I've got so far. Pretty simple:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="button">Lorem ipsum dolar</div>
    <div class="button">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.button { display: inline-block; min-width: 50px; }
```

Comment: could you share your markup and the css you are using please

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap similar buttons in a container div with a desired width and set the inners divs to:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
```

This will allow you to edit the widths of a logical grouping in one place.

Comment: Manually specifying a width for each group was one of the things I wanted to avoid (see bullet #1).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'll want to wrap them in a container the same way, without defining a min-width on that div. Then for the inner divs you will still set them to:
`box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;`
The container div will inherit its width from the largest width of it's child divs, and the rest will expand to that inherited width.

Comment: After double checking my work, I discovered an error on my part. This solution does the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Key for me to make this work was to set the wrapper div to `display: inline-block`. I didn't understand why this wasn't working for me until I did that.

Answer (score 1):

wrap them both in a container.

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="button">Hi</div>
    <div class="button">Wassup</div>
    <div class="button">Yo</div>
</div>
```

then apply css like this:

```
    display:inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
```

and then set the div "group"  that groups those divs in the width you wanted to

Comment: This just sets the buttons to 100% width of the container (which itself is 100% because it is just `display: block`). So short buttons end up wasting a lot of space and stretching across the page...

Answer (score 0):

Use min-width and max-width:

```
div{/*use the selector what you're using*/
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

If you want to get a uniform width, then you have to define a class name and style like this:

```
.width1{
  width: 200px;
}

.width2{
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This does nothing to align buttons that are less than the max-width... Ex: 200px & 250px.

Comment: There's only this way you can do. This aligns the smaller divs not greater divs.